# Where is the asymmetry in my calculations for matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices

Where there is a comma, the numbers after that are the second row

$$A= 
\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\0& 0
\end{bmatrix},\ 
B= 
\begin{bmatrix}0& 1\\0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I got 
$$(A+B)^2=\begin{bmatrix} 1& 2\\0& 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

I also got
$$A^2+2AB+B^2=\begin{bmatrix} 1& 3\\0& 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

$(A+B)^2$ should equal $A^2+2Ab+B^2$ so where is my mistake?

I also got the following calculations

$$
A^2=\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\0& 0
\end{bmatrix},\ 
AB=
\begin{bmatrix}0& 1\\0& 0
\end{bmatrix},\ 
2AB=
\begin{bmatrix}0& 2\\0& 0
\end{bmatrix},\ 
B^2=
\begin{bmatrix}0& 1\\0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Also how do I get the whole matrix in big brackets on this site?

Comment: is your $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: @EmilioNovati yes

Comment: look at my edit for the use of {bmatrix}.

Answer (score 4):

In general case matrix multiplication in *not commutative*. Therefore, you can only say that
$$(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+BA+B^2.$$

Comment: Yes, $AB =BA$ only happens if A or B is the identity matrix $I$. This is also true if $A=B^-1$ or visa versa. Well said above.

Comment: @MathHype this is quite false. For a given matrix $A$ there is a space of matrices that commutes with $A$. Also, matrices that commute *with every matrix* have the form $cI$ where $c$ is a scalar and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: So I will posit you the leaving out of $cI$ as an oversight. Is there a way to determine a generalized solution for the other matrices which commute with an arbitrary matrix $A$? Any link to this would be appreciated.

Comment: @MathHype I have never encountered such a description. At least, if $f$ is a holomorphic function with holomorphic domain containing all eigenvalues of $A$, then you can define a matrix $f(A)$ and it will commute with $A$. In particular, if $f(x)$ is a polynomial  or $f(x)=e^x$.